# How to use std::search on a std::vector passed by reference?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, iterator, pass-by-reference

If I have a function in C++ that gets an `std::vector<unsigned char>` by reference, how can I use `std::search` to find a signature?

The code looks like this:

```
int check (const std::vector<unsigned char>& vect)
{
  std::string signature("<!-- signature -->");
  std::string signature2("<!-- another -->");
  std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator itr;
  unsigned int kind = 0;

  itr = std::search(vect.begin(),vect.end(),signature.begin(),signature.end());
  if (itr!=vect.end()) kind=1;
  if (kind == 0) 
  {
    itr = std::search(vect.begin(),vect.end(),signature2.begin(),signature2.end());
    if (itr!=vect.end()) kind=2;
  }
  return kind;
}
```

`vect` is huge , so copying it works , but is a bad solution.

Why this doesn't compile?

Comment: What does the compiler tell you...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are iterating over a `const std::vector<unsigned char>`, but you try to assign an iterator from that to a non-const `std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator`.

A simple fix would be to declare the correct type for `itr`:

```
std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator itr;
```

If you're using C++11, I would just use `auto` instead:

```
auto itr = std::search(vect.begin(),vect.end(),signature.begin(),signature.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

Works fine with gcc-5.1, [example here](http://ideone.com/vurQLn):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool check (const std::vector<unsigned char>& vect)
{
  std::string signature("<!-- signature -->");
  auto itr = std::search(vect.begin(),vect.end(),signature.begin(),signature.end());
  if (itr!=vect.end()) /* do something */
    return false;
}

int main() {
    check(std::vector<unsigned char>{'a', 'b', 'c'});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I corrected my code when I made the example. I used std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator itr;

Comment: Your code works, but my code is much more complex than the example.

Comment: @R.F.Luis So you want us to address problems which we cannot reproduce in code which you haven't shown us? Good luck with that...

Comment: Sorry, sorry. I can't post tens of kB of code, so I had to make an example.

Comment: @R.F.Luis That's of course the correct course of action, but the exampel has to faithfully reproroduce the actual error!

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**: The below is wrong.  The problem is that the code in the question doesn't actually show the problem.  TartanLlama has the right solution.

**Edit2**: Sigh: I was having a bad day when I wrote this.  There *are* times when the difference between `char` and `unsigned char` will cause problems - they are distinct types.  The reference to "char defaults to signed on Windows" however is misleading; it *is* true that whether `char` is signed or not is implementation defined (and on Windows it defaults to signed), but regardless of whether it is signed or unsigned, it is still a distinct type from either `unsigned char` or `signed char`.

Your problem is that `std::string::begin` returns an iterator to char, and your vector contains *unsigned* char.  I suspect you are on windows, where char defaults to signed.

The fix is to do a reinterpret cast (which in this case is safe):

```
const auto sigstart = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&signature.front());
const auto itr = std::search(vect.begin(), vect.end(),
                             sigstart, sigstart+signature.len());
```

Comment: That's not the problem at all, `char` and `unsigned char` can be compared with `==` just fine.

Comment: @Angew: Yup.  Got it :-(.

Comment: Not piling on, but this seems to be a common misunderstanding. `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are **three** distinct types; the choice of signed or unsigned for plain `char` is implementation-specific, but doesn't change the fact that `char` is a distinct type, i.e., it is neither `signed char` nor `unsigned char`.

Comment: @PeteBecker:  Good point.